# How to call graphql API's

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

How to call graphql API's inside a view controller.I am calling an API like the below structure

```
let url = URL(string: "http://xxxx.com/graphql")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let query = "{query:mutation {\n  signin(email: \"adc.inlove@gmail.com\", password: \"qwerty\") {\n    result {\n      token\n      firstName\n      lastName\n      profileImage\n      status\n    }\n  }\n}\n}"
let body = ["query": query]
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("Data is missing."); return }
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
        print(json)
    } catch let e {
        print("Parse error: \(e)")
    }
})
task.resume()`
```

But it showing the error as,

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

and also it works perfectly in postman and getting output.Anyone please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Your service is not providing correct JSON

Comment: It is the type of GraphQL API , so I think it should be passed like this only...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the document that you're currently sending:

```
{
  query:mutation  {
    signin(email: "adc.inlove@gmail.com", password: "qwerty") {
      result {
        token
        firstName
        lastName
        profileImage
        status
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not correct syntax for a GraphQL document. Based on the spec, a document should have the following format:

```
OperationType [Name] [VariableDefinitions] [Directives] SelectionSet
```

where brackets denote optional elements, an operation type is one of `query`, `mutation` or `subscription` and a selection set is one or more fields wrapped in a set of curly brackets.

If the operation type is omitted, the document is assumed to be a query. This is known as "query shorthand". So given a valid query like:

```
query SomeOperationName {
  users {
    name
  }
}
```

The following is equivalent:

```
{
  users {
    name
  }
}
```

The above only applies to queries, though, and not mutations. Given all the above, your document has an extra set of curly brackets and an invalid operation type. Minimally, change it to:

```
mutation {
  signin (email: "adc.inlove@gmail.com", password: "qwerty") {
    result {
      token
      firstName
      lastName
      profileImage
      status
    }
  }
}
```

or...

```
let query = "mutation { signin(email: \"adc.inlove@gmail.com\", password: \"qwerty\") { result { token firstName lastName profileImage status } } }"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ....I don't know how to express my thanks.You saved me.And I need one more help, This is ok for normal API calling and if I have to do this with apollo method The API.swift file is always an empty file can you please help me to find out what's wrong with my project.

Comment: I haven't worked with Apollo iOS yet, so I'm not quite sure. According to the docs "because Apollo iOS generates query-specific result types, API.swift will be mostly empty at this point unless you’ve already added some .graphql files with queries or mutations to your target directory". I would start with the docs here and go from there: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html